# Why am I getting an HRESULT 0x800A03EC Exception when using Range.AddComment

Tags: vb.net, excel, runtime-error

I can't seem to find a question about this error in the context of Range.AddComment

I am using code that goes through a selected row and adds comments to each cell.  Sometimes it will write a comment in a cell that already contains a comment.  I'm not sure if I'm getting this error because I'm using .AddComment on a cell that already contains a comment, or if it's for some other reason related to my range.

```
 If IsDBNull(pobjComment) Then
                mwksSheet.Range(strExcelCol(pintCol) & (pintRow + 1)).AddComment(Nothing)
 Else
                mwksSheet.Range(strExcelCol(pintCol) & (pintRow + 1)).AddComment(pobjComment)
 End If
```

the pobjComment is a generic object; In the cases I use it, I pass it a string value from the extended properties of a DataColumn.

The error occurs when the pobjComment is actually something.  If the problem is Adding comments over other comments..  then I'm wondering if I should try deleting any existing comments first, or checking to see if the values are identical before I try adding...

Comment: You can't do this: `AddComment(Nothing)`  Are you trying to remove any existing comment, or trying to add an empty comment?  You can test for an existing comment using `If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then...`

Comment: Go it, the AddComment(Nothing) has never actually run before.  This code was being reused from a different project that used other software with similar functionality, and AddComment(Nothing) was valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the .AddComment lead to a 0x800A03EC error when my programm tried to add comment on a cell that already had a commentline. It seems logic that the error occurs because a cell cannot have multiple comment Objects. In my case clearing the current comment before adding the new one solved the problem.